# I am getting nullpointer exception while running AWS Redshift docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to set up Redshift docker. Whenever I am trying to run the container using my java code I am getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon][JDBC](11380) Null pointer exception.
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.startSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

I have a properties file with below details:

```
REDSHIFT_JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL = jdbc:redshift://localhost:5439/testDb
REDSHIFT_JDBC_USERNAME=test
REDSHIFT_JDBC_PASSWORD=
REDSHIFT_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE=21
```

And then I have used Hikari to get the datasouce:

```
public DataSource redshiftDataSource() {
   HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME"));
    config.setJdbcUrl(this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_URL"));
    config.setLeakDetectionThreshold((Long)this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_LEAK_DETECTION_THRESHOLD", Long.TYPE));
    config.setMaximumPoolSize((Integer)this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_MAX_POOL_SIZE", Integer.TYPE));
    config.setMinimumIdle((Integer)this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_MINIMUM_IDLE", Integer.TYPE));
    config.setPoolName(this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_POOL_NAME"));
    config.setUsername(this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_USERNAME"));
    config.setPassword(this.env.getRequiredProperty("REDSHIFT_JDBC_PASSWORD"));
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

And then I've used this datasource for rest of the work.

I am using this docker image to test the connection : https://hub.docker.com/r/guildeducation/docker-amazon-redshift/.
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like it's probably a bad configuration, maybe missing something that's needed for Redshift. Show the configuration/code that you use to create the connection pool.

Comment: @Parsifal I've updated the configuration that I'm using in the problem description. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not providing a password. That could certainly cause a NPE from code that establishes a new connection.

You say that you have a "properties" file, but that looks more like environment variable settings. Assuming that's the case, and that you're using `docker run` to start your container, you can provide the password on the command-line:

```
docker run -d --rm -e REDSHIFT_JDBC_PASSWORD=my_secret_password CONTAINER:TAG
```

Alternatively, you could store your environment settings in a file, and provide it to the container using the `--env-file` argument.